# What tool do I need to press fit a "Spanish" bottom bracket?

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, bottom-bracket, build, jumping

I bought a BMX style bottom bracket called a "Spanish" bottom bracket for a dirt jumper.

Instead of using a hammer and a block of wood, I would like to do it correctly with a press... however, I'm not sure what specs I should be looking for in the press?

How do I buy the right press for the job?

I know asking for specific products is against the rules, so if you could just explain the specs for what I should Google to find the right press.

[This is my bottom bracket](http://www.jensonusa.com/Profile-Racing-19mm-Bottom-Bracket-Gold?pt_source=googleads&pt_medium=cpc&pt_campaign=shopping_us&pt_keyword=&gclid=EAIaIQobChMItaXS_NDO2wIVi1cNCh0xeQhTEAQYAyABEgK7zPD_BwE)... it is 19mm inner diameter and 73mm width
[image]

[This is my frame](https://www.deitycomponents.com/store/p55/DEITY_CRYPTKEEPER_FRAME.html)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rather trivial answer is look at the documentation for various bottom bracket presses and see if a bushing set for the BMX Spanish type is available.

For example the [Park Tool BBP-1](https://www.parktool.com/product/bottom-bracket-bearing-press-set-bbp-1) documentation explicitly specifies that it supports the BMX Spanish type.

If the Spanish BB is not listed you need a press that has an bushing set that works with a 19mm axle and 37mm outer bearing race.

This is the type of task where rather than buy a tool that costs several hundred of dollars it is better to go to your local bike repair shop and have their mechanic do it or go to a bike repair co-op and rent space and tools for the 15 minutes it will take you to press the bearings.

Comment: Question: is "axel" synonymous to "spindle"? I could never figure out if the "axel" refers to the spacer in-between the BB or the spindle that comes with cranks

Comment: Man, you might be right. That Park Tools MSRP's for $200

Comment: I just saw a video that says you can build the tool with parts from Home Depot

Comment: @KolobCanyon Axle/spindle colloquially means the same thing, although I think technically an axle does not rotate but a spindle does. So wheels have an axle and cranks have a spindle.

Comment: @KolobCanyon Yes, home made bearing presses are possible, you just need to be sure the 'bushing' presses on the outer bearing race, *not* the inner, and that the bearings go in straight. My LBS would happily press BB or headset bearings for me and charge me for 5 mins of shop time, which is very cost effective.

Comment: I think you are right. It is more cost effective to bring to the LBS. At least I now know how to put a bottom bracket in, which is a good learning experience

Comment: Echoing what @ArgentiApparatus says, it's pretty tough to justify owning a bearing press unless it's in a professional shop setting. I found one on a discount website that was less than $100 but most start well above that and can run over $400 for the park "gold plated" versions. When you build a bike every few years just have your LBS do it for you - don't forget the headset as well!